# refactor existing observable to add conditional behaviour

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an existing rxjs flow shown below.

```
const existingFlow$ = concat(firstCall$,usecaseflow$);
```

it uses concat to call firstCall$ and then usecaseflow$

I would like to modify this so that I first make a service call (logsheet service)

and depending on the result I either call to redirect or continue with

my existing flow ie. call existingFlow$

I've previously used filter and merge for conditionals in rxjs but for this case

I'm not sure how to integrate the result$ flow.

this is my incomplete attempt.

```
const no1$ = this.logSheetService.getActiveLogsheet().pipe(
      share()
    );
            
const norRedirect$ = no1$.pipe(
      filter((logsheet: Logsheet) => isRedirect(logsheet)),
      tap(() => console.log("redirected.."))
    );        
              
const continue$ = no1$.pipe(
      filter((logsheet: Logsheet) => !isRedirect(logsheet)),
      tap(() => console.log("continue..")),
      CALL RESULT$  !!!!!
    );

continue$.merge(norRedirect$);
```

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Usually for merging multiple observables you need to use higher order mapping operators like `switchMap`, `concatMap` or `mergeMap`. In your case when you want to conditionally switch to another observable you could use `switchMap`. For example something like this:

```
  result$ = this.logSheetService.getActiveLogsheet().pipe(
    switchMap((logSheet) => {
      if (logSheet && isRedirect(logsheet)) {
        return of(logSheet);
      } else {
        return never();
      }
    }),
    switchMap(logSheet => this.logSheetService.print(logSheet))
  );
```

In this example we call `logSheetService` service, get the result. Check if the result is OK and we can continue. If we can continue we return the result and make another call. If we cannot continue we return `never()` and the following switch never gets called.

Comment: Why not return empty instead of never? Empty doesn't risk a memory leak and also won't affect the following switchmap

Comment: We could however, we are not subscribing here, so I assume we will use async pipe. Thus no possibility for a memory leak.

Comment: thanks for your comments, but what I really want to find out is it possible to call my existing observable result$ if the condition is true.

Comment: Angular isn't tagged here at all, I don't think it's wise to assume they're using a specific SPA framework when asking a question about a separate library! :)

Comment: thanks, updated with angular tag